# Spectrum Analyzer: Resolution Bandwidth vs Acquisition Time

Tags: spectrum-analyzer, resolution

Why a smaller resolution bandwidth (RBW) in a swept tuned spectrum analyzer RBW requires longer acquisition time?

Answer (score 2):

Filters delay signals - it's never instantaneous. Filters that have a very-tight pass-band produce a longer delay than filters that are wide-band. When you require a higher resolution, the filtering in the spectrum analyser becomes "tighter" and therefore produces a longer delay.

Looking at it another way - if you were weighing a bag of nails, you'd weigh it and get an answer. If you weighed the nails individually you'd get the same gross weight but it'll take longer. The benefit in weighing all the nails is that you get more detail - if that is what you are looking for.

Comment: "Filters that have a very-tight pass-band produce a longer delay than filters that are wide-band."
Any reference / equation for this statement?

Comment: @PaoloMinotti look-up "group delay" on the internet for the maths. The way I visualize it is in acoustics - imagine two guitar strings tuned to the same pitch. If you pluck one string it is forced into oscillation immediately. The 2nd string will take a certain amount of time to form a sympathetic resonance.

Comment: My favourite explanation is "to distinguish between two frequencies, I need to see enough of the signal to decide, and two similar frequency signals are going to look similar over short intervals"

Answer (score 0):

Lower bandwidth simply means things are happening more slowly!

If you don't increase the acquisition time to match (on analyzers where you can control RBW and acq time separately) you will miss the events you are looking for - or at least, the measurements of them will be inaccurate.

Comment: I mean: I have a sinusoidal voltage: V = V_0 * sin (2 pi f_0 t). Why, if I measure this signal with 2 different RBWs, the acquisition time is different (while the result is obviously the same)? Why does it take so long to acquire the signal if I reduce the bandwidth? Which equation describes this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

In this context, Smaller resolution bandwidth implies higher resolution.

100Hz resolution BW is higher resolution than 300Hz.

With 300Hz RBW, you are sweeping and integrating across every 300Hz. With 100Hz RBW, you are sweeping and integrating across every 100Hz. To be able to resolve slower signals, you have to dwell longer in/on each "bin."

Consider 300Hz -->1/300Hz = .003 seconds. 100Hz -> 1/100Hz = .01 seconds. If you acquire all your energy in .003 seconds, you can't determine the frequency content to anything finer than 300Hz.

Comment: Can't suggest an edit because it changes fewer than 6 characters: it's 0.01s.

Answer (score -1):

Using a smaller RBW means one is sweeping using smaller channels. Hence, smaller RBW will need to "stitch more channels together" for a given frequency span.

A spectrum requires certain dwell time on each channel or sweep point.

Hence it takes a longer time using smaller RBW to sweep across a given frequency span.

Comment: You are getting caught up in the issues of a particular implementation, but the issue of the question is one that persists regardless of implementation.  Consider for example that it is perfectly possible in theory (and even in practice unconstrained by economics) to sample all of your "channels" at the exact same time.  Yet even when doing so, the issue of the question would remain.

Comment: The user is not asking for sampling (vector signal measurement) but rather using sweep tuned. Please answer to user's concern.